# How can I make dot product of vector and matrix faster in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

My code works however it's fairly slow and i need to run it multiple times so it's very inefficient. i am positive there is a more efficient way of calculating it.

The code is an implementation of this equation:
[image: MMD]

where k(x,y) is the dot product of the two vectors
xi and yj are the rows i,j of the two matrices A and B, respectively.

I'd like to also note that the number of rows in each matrix is in the thousands.

here is my code

```
m=size(A,1);
Kxx=0;
for i=1:m
    x=A(i,:);
    X=A(i+1:end,:);
    Kxx=Kxx+2*sum(dot(ones(m-i,1)*x,X,2));
end
Kxx=Kxx/(m*(m-1));

n=size(B,1);
Kyy=0;
for j=1:n
   y=B(j,:);
   YY=B(j+1:end,:);
   Kyy=Kyy+2*sum(dot(ones(n-j,1)*y,YY,2));
end
Kyy=Kyy/(n*(n-1));

Kxy=0;
for i=1:m
    x=A(i,:);
   for j=1:n
       y=B(j,:);
       Kxy=Kxy+dot(x,y);
   end
end
Kxy=Kxy*2/(m*n);

Dxy=Kxx+Kyy-Kxy;
```

Comment: To speed up, you need to eliminate all your loops.  Can you describe what each loop is doing in English?

Comment: I think the last block can be written as `Kxy=sum(sum(A*B.'));`, the previous ones are a bit harder. If someone doesn't jump un the opportunity, I'll add an answer when I'll have time to consider those cases as well.

Comment: What is this code supposed to be doing?

Comment: I've edited the question to show what the code is implementing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your edit makes our jub *much* easier. Here's what you just have to do for a fully vectorized solution:

```
C=A*A';  %'
Kxx=sum(sum(C-diag(diag(C))))/m/(m-1);
C=B*B';  %'
Kyy=sum(sum(C-diag(diag(C))))/n/(n-1);
Kxy=2*mean(reshape(A*B.',[],1));   %'

Dxy=Kxx+Kyy-Kxy;
```

Thanks to [@hiandbaii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883252/how-can-i-make-dot-product-of-vector-and-matrix-faster-in-matlab/34884389#comment57511981_34884389) for pointing out that the equivalent of `dot` for complex vectors involves the conjugate transpose rather than the transpose.

---

Original, looping version for <strike>historical</strike> sentimental reasons:

I'm not sure whether the first two loops can be vectorized without huge memory overhead. So while I figure this out, here's a version in which the first two loops are a bit simplified, and the third loop is replaced by a vectorized operation:

```
%dummy input data
A=rand(5);
B=rand(5);

m=size(A,1);
Kxx=0;
for l=1:m
    x=A(l,:);
    X=A(l+1:end,:);
    Kxx=Kxx+2*sum(X*x.');         %'
end
Kxx=Kxx/(m*(m-1));

n=size(B,1);
Kyy=0;
for l=1:n
   y=B(l,:);
   YY=B(l+1:end,:);
   Kyy=Kyy+2*sum(YY*y.');         %'
end
Kyy=Kyy/(n*(n-1));

Kxy=2*mean(reshape(A*B.',[],1));  %'

Dxy=Kxx+Kyy-Kxy;
```

Comment: Here's a stinky little comment.

Comment: Comment on your original loopy version. It doesn't produce the same result as OP's original code if A has complex elements. Need to use conjugate transpose.

Comment: @hiandbaii are you sure? I don't see a single conjugation in OP's code, how could it be needed then? Ooooh, due to `dot`?

Comment: The Matrices are not complex at the time being but thanks for noticing i'll keep that in mind If i add that later.
@AndrasDeak  i am running the original code at the moment. once it finishes i'll run the loopy version and see how it compares.

Comment: @mhmsa your update made my job much easier, I'll be right back with a great solution:)

Comment: I was actually about to write what you posted in your vectorized solution until you made an edit. Nice job.

Comment: Thanks:) And thanks @hiandbaii for the note about the adjoint, you're right, I never use `dot`.

Comment: Thanks the last version is a lot faster and gives the same answer.
The Sentimental version produces different result though it might have a typo

Comment: @mhmsa are you sure you didn't run the dummy  `5 x 5` data generating part?:) I should probably remove that now...

Comment: @mhmsa sorry, I see now, I only tested the looping one with square matrices. Let me see...

Comment: @mhmsa nope, I still get `-0.030334915146074` vs `-0.030334915146057` for non-rectangular matrices. They are `~isequal()`, but the same up to machine precision. How huge difference do you get?

Comment: I reran it again after clearing matlab workspace and you are right the difference is miniscule